# How to recursively copy specific file and keep name of parent directory

Tags: unix, search, copy-paste

I have a multiple folders with different names: folderA, FolderB etc.
Within each of these folders are multiple files: fileA, fileB, fileC etc.

I want to search through all these folders and copy only specific files to a new location but with the same parent folder name: e.g. I want to generate:

```
new_location/folderA/fileA
new_location/folderA/fileC
new_location/folderB/fileA
new_location/folderB/fileC
```

Could anyone suggest the unix commands that would accomplish this?

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 1):

This depends somewhat, on how you can or do specify your specific files.

find folderA folderB folderC -type d -exec mkdir -p new_location/{} \;
will should make the proper subdirectories

find folderA folderB folderB -name *somepattern* -exec cp {} new_location/{} \;

may or may not need to worry about an extra "/" depending on directory names, etc

Comment: you can use `cp --parent` to avoid having to create the directories with  `find ... -exec mkdir`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Even better